# How can I remove external access to specific url of my domain

Tags: html, web

I developed a contact form for my site and it is working and redirects to another url inside my domain when it is sent (for example lets say domain.com/sent). The thing is, if someone by chance decides to access the url domain.com/sent directly, it can be accessed like if he had submitted the form and was redirected there. I also have configured a 404 error custom page for any other page outside the existing ones, is there any way of disabling the domain.com/sent external access and redirecting to the error 404 page and keeping the sent page only for the users who really submitted the form?

Comment: What are the details of the environment you're serving the website on?

Answer (score 0):

Have the response to the POST request to the form handler set a cookie.

Have the handler for `/sent` test for that cookie and:

- If it is set:

  - Delete the cookie
  - Display the sent page
- If it not send:

  - Do something different such as displaying an error or redirecting

Comment: so you mean, the user has to accept the cookies for accessing the domain/sent site? Wouldn´t this create a problem if the cookies were accepted on a previous session, as the user would be able to access the URL anywise?

Comment: @DiegoManzanares — No since, as I said, you delete the cookie when displaying the sent page.